# How to set the style transform using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prefix

i want to add the `transform: scale()` property using Javascript.
but for transform prefix not working :

```
var $square = $('#homepage');
$square.css('zoom', r);
$square.css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + r + ')');
$square.css(  '-o-transform', 'scale(' + r + ')');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "";
element.style.MozTransform = "";
element.style.msTransform = "";
element.style.OTransform = "";
element.style.transform = "";
```

Or jquery:

```
$(element).css({
    "webkitTransform":"",
    "MozTransform":"",
    "msTransform":"",
    "OTransform":"",
    "transform":""
});
```

Comment: not sure why no-one has upvoted you before. this works a treat for me across all major browsers (tests successfully back to IE9 inclusive)

Answer (score 2):

Try using something like this:

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "scale()";
```

Comment: how about with -moz-, -o- ?

Comment: Isn't it invalid to have `scale` with no parameter?

Comment: replace the webkitTransform with Moz or MS etc... and the scale() was just an example, i think he knows to add the parameter back in :)

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery 1.8, there is no need to include vendor prefixes - jQuery will do this automatically, if required. Vendor prefixes are becoming less required as support for CSS3 increases.

If you *are* using < 1.8, then you probably need to manually amend the `style` attribute.

```
var $h = $('#h');
$h.css({
    background:'#f00'
});
var s = $h.attr('style');
s += '-moz-transform: scale(2);';
$h.attr('style',s);
```